# Video enters fullscreen but will not exit (iOS 6.1)

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

I am using a custom movie player to play videos with MPMoviePlayer as the base, and while the player will enter fullscreen fine when **setFullscreen:YES** is called, it won't exit fullscreen when **setFullscreen:NO** is called.

I have tried:

- adding the video's view as a subview of a smaller window, and resetting the view's frame
- using notifications as I show below (based on what I read in another question about this problem)

Here is the code I am currently using. None of the answers I have seen have solved the problem for me, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (IBAction)fullScreenPressed:(id)sender {
    if ([self mediaIsVideo]){
        if ([self.videoController.moviePlayer isFullscreen]){
            [self.videoController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
            UIImage *full = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fullscreen-vector-icon.png"];
            [self.videoFullscreenButton setImage:full forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            //video is in fullscreen, add notification observer
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitFullscreen) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
            [self.videoController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
            UIImage *undoFull = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fullscreen-exit-vector-icon.png"];
            [self.videoFullscreenButton setImage:undoFull forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
}

-(void)exitFullscreen{
    if ([self mediaIsVideo]){
        NSLog(@"notification selector called");
        [self.videoController.moviePlayer setFullscreen:NO animated:YES];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
    }
}
```